# How to list multiple files with the same name in different directories in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a project in ${TOPLEVEL_DIR} compiled with two sources:

```
 ${TOPLEVEL_DIR}/feature.c
 ${TOPLEVEL_DIR}/test/feature.c
```

Functions from the second file call functions from the first file.  The second contains `main()`.

I don't need advice on naming files here - they're not mine and I can't change them.

What I do need to know is how to list these files in a gdb session.

If the current location is line 450 in `${TOPLEVEL_DIR}/feature.c`, and I say `list`, I get line 450 of `${TOPLEVEL_DIR}/feature.c`, no problem.

But, then if I type `list 420` to back up a little, I get an error:

```
 file: "test/feature.c", line number: 420, symbol: "???"
 Line number 415 out of range; test/feature.c has 196 lines.
```

gdb "forgets" what the current source is.   I cannot figure out a way to specify which it should list based on the online help or manual.   I want to type something like `list feature.c:420` or `list ./feature.c:420` - but alas, those does not work.

So how can I list previous lines in the file that is current in the activated frame in this case?

Comment: try removing "./" from file name.

Comment: Works for me (Win 10, MinGW-W64 8.1.0) with a really simple [example], which is missed from the question. ;-)

Comment: @mangupt - Yes, if it is not obvious from what I've said, that does not work either.  Edited to make that clear.

Comment: Which Gcc version you are using? other details. I tried G++ it works for that also.

Comment: You need to show a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or at least specify version of `gcc` and `gdb` and compilation commands used.